# Error with the package algorithm2e in springer template

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I'm using the Springer Latex template, the package algorithm2e is not acceptable (error). I tried to insert the package in "`sn-jnl.cls`" but that did not work.
They use these packages:

```
 \usepackage{algorithm}%
    \usepackage{algorithmicx}%
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}%
```

Whenever I write `\kwdata{var}`, an error is generated. Besides the vertical line is not displayed (for example: from while to end). I tried to insert the package `tikz` in "`sn-jnl.cls`" to use the `\AddNote` instruction but I couldn't.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

`\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}`

as described in [Algorithms and Listings](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-23816-1_10). The `algo2e` option [works in the following way](https://mlg.ulb.ac.be/files/algorithm2e.pdf):

> 5 The options of the package
>
> algo2e: changes the name of environment algorithm into algorithm2e and so allows to use the
> package with some journal style which already define an algorithm environment. Changes
> also the command name for the list of algorithms, it becomes \listofalgorithmes

I can confirm that the vertical lines are displayed.